# Is this question too detailed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Did I give too much info on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764331/dealing-with-matrices-in-cuda-understanding-basic-concepts)? Was it redundant to write all the general procedure, to help readers understand the code? Is the code necessary even if I provided an easily-accessible MCVE? (For the latter I guess so)

I just wanted to know if too much info given on a question can be misleading or unnecessary.

Comment: the question seems to be very clear...

Comment: Just a quick question: what’s an MWE? Minimal Working Example?

Comment: Yep. Should it be MCWE?

Comment: @Eugenio Call it MCVE.

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jpmc26 It’s [M**CV**E](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JF Yay for typos. Good catch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think there's too much info in that question.  It's entirely appropriate to spend a few sentences briefly describing what the purpose of the code snippet is.  It's not always *necessary* (although sometimes it is) to add some greater context to the code beyond what the specific problem with it is, but it's typically helpful, so long as it's a suitably brief description (yours seems fine in length).

As for whether all of the code was necessary, I don't know enough about the subject matter to comment.  It's not so long that I'd be super worried about trying to shorten it, but perhaps a subject matter might be able to realize that you could cut 1/3 of it out without meaningfully changing the question; I wouldn't know.  If such a change would be possible, it would likely be helpful, although it's not so long of a snippet as is that I'd consider it *essential* for the question to shorten the code.

All that said, you do have enough information that you probably do want to be rather mindful about how you format it, not just what you include.  Burying the actual question halfway through the question, with several paragraphs of preceding information and several paragraphs of following information, isn't ideal.  It more or less forces the reader to read the whole thing just to figure out what you're actually asking.  You bolded the question, which does help, but really it's better if you can just lead with the question, so that you don't *need* to bold it.  If you open with the problem you're having, then explain your code and then, if necessary, repeat the question later (about where you have your question now) once you've finished setting up the question.

In general when you're writing a question that is adding information that you think might be useful, but may also not be essential to an answerer, you want to be careful about where you put it in the question.  Ensure that readers *start* by reading everything that's essential and *then* move on to supplemental information that might be helpful, but also may not be necessary.  When you *start* with the supplemental information, and then move on to the critical information, you risk people missing some of the critical information, or simply giving up on your question and moving on because reading the first half didn't give them any idea what the question is actually about.

Comment: That's a good answer, I'll keep it in mind (and edit the post of course). Thx!

Comment: Just a question out of your discussion: is it acceptable for a questioner to show only a part of the code, with an external link (like I did) and then as an answer share the whole code? (I can ask this question in another Question if necessary (I'm doing meta-meta-stackoverflow))

Comment: @Eugenio Posting the complete code externally is a big no; link rot is a major reason for this. But aside from link rot, if you're doing it for length reasons, that would usually indicate that your MVCE wasn't minimal enough. An *answer* is certainly not the place for additional detail about the question, though; such an "answer" would be rightly flagged as "Not an Answer."

Comment: @jpmc26 OK then, understood. By the way, I moved my question here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342051/5794332